# What are the differences between "field.appendText" and "field.htmltext ="

Tags: actionscript-3, htmltext, appendtext

Ihave been  looking  it for a day but  I couldnt find any answer.
What are the differences between the following 2 codes. (Performance,operation etc..)

First Code

```
tField.appendText("<font color='#7f7f7f'>" + TahminTxt.text + "\n</font>");
tField.htmlText=tField.Text;
```

Second Code

```
tField.htmlText+="<font color='#7f7f7f'>" + TahminTxt.text + "\n</font>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of operation I believe the end result is equivalent however appendText is much faster seen in the docs, on others forums, and in my own testing:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7ffc.html